# PHP - why does php think that a random string is equal to true?

Tags: php

[Code](https://onlinephp.io/c/b0169):

```
$x = true;

if ($x == "continue") {
    $x = "foo";
}

echo $x;    // prints "foo"
```

I know I can use `===` instead to solve it, but I wonder why PHP thinks that a string is equal to true?

Comment: `==` doesn't check the type. Both values when cast to boolean are true, therefore equal.

Comment: One of the best resource on that topic https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a non-empty string is considered `true` and an empty string is `false`.

Google for "truthiness" for more info. And yes, a lot of it is bonkers. Just wait until you hear about how JavaScript does it.

Comment: Thank you. I bet there are tens of thousands of unidentified bugs out there because of this ...*facepalm*.